# UITableView crashes after trying to delete a cell the *second* time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

another weird problem with the iPhone SDK here.

I have a `UITableView` which contains a custom `UITableViewCell`. This table gets its data from a mutable array, which in turn pulls it from a Core Data storage.

**The problem:** If I enter editing mode and delete a cell, it works for the first time - the cell is successfully removed from the `UITableView` and the Core Data database. However, if I attempt to **delete another cell, the application crashes after clicking the Delete button for the row** (the one that actually fires the action, not the button that rotates itself to reveal its partner).

This is my code for the `UITableView` delegate method corresponding to the deletion of rows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete ) {
        NSManagedObject *dream = [dreamsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:dream];

        [dreamsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // removing from instance field array works fine, but...
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        // ... crash right here

        NSError *error = nil;
        if ( ![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] )
            NSLog(@"DreamsViewController:140 %@", error);
    }
}
```

I tracked down the problematic method to find `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` was (surprisingly) the culprit. I have tried exiting the editing mode, visiting another view, and revisiting this table to delete another, but this didn't work, either.

---

**Update:** I have added a test to ensure that an incorrect row value is not given to the UITableView after deleting an element, causing it to crash. Modified code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete ) {
        NSManagedObject *dream = [dreamsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:dream];

        // outputs right before a cell is deleted
        NSLog(@"before\tarray\t%d", [dreamsArray count]);

        [dreamsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if ( ![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] )
            NSLog(@"DreamsViewController:129 %@", error);
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // outputs after a cell is deleted
    NSLog(@"after\tarray\t%d", [dreamsArray count]);
    return [dreamsArray count];
}
```

The debug console showed no sort of logic error with the cell's removal (and the removal of its corresponding object):

```
** pressed "Delete" for the first time **
2009-09-21 16:47:12.567 xxx[774:20b] before array   11
2009-09-21 16:47:12.568 xxx[774:20b] after  array   10

** pressed "Delete" on another cell after first deletion finished **
2009-09-21 16:47:17.685 xxx[774:20b] before array   10
2009-09-21 16:47:17.686 xxx[774:20b] after  array   9
** after this output, CRASH occurs **
```

---

**Update:** Here is the stack trace:

```
#0  0x94292688 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x016c867d in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] ()
#2  0x000038c4 in -[DreamsViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (self=0x3e1e380, _cmd=0x29cfb18, tableView=0x401b800, indexPath=0x3e4ece0) at /Users/hans/Projects/xxx/Classes/DreamsViewController.m:85
#3  0x016cee60 in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] ()
#4  0x016c6a97 in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] ()
#5  0x01866a18 in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForExistingOffscreenCells] ()
#6  0x01869a28 in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport initWithTableView:updateItems:oldRowData:newRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] ()
#7  0x016d6a2b in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateWithItems:withOldRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] ()
#8  0x016d6757 in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] ()
#9  0x016c8a77 in -[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] ()
#10 0x00003ec3 in -[DreamsViewController tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] (self=0x3e1e380, _cmd=0x29cfaa0, tableView=0x401b800, editingStyle=UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete, indexPath=0x3e4e380) at /Users/hans/Projects/xxx/Classes/DreamsViewController.m:125
#11 0x016c66fc in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] ()
#12 0x0167f459 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#13 0x016e2ba2 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#14 0x016e4dc3 in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#15 0x016e3b0f in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#16 0x01698e33 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#17 0x0168281c in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#18 0x016890b5 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#19 0x0001def1 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#20 0x00843b80 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#21 0x00842c48 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#22 0x0001c7ad in GSEventRunModal ()
#23 0x0001c872 in GSEventRun ()
#24 0x0168a003 in UIApplicationMain ()
#25 0x00005461 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffef54) at /Users/hans/Projects/xxx/main.m:14
```

So, after looking through the stack trace, it looks like `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` has something to do with this problem, too. Here is the code that calls that method, though I don't see anything wrong with this, either..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"dreamCell";

    DreamTableCell *cell = (DreamTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if ( cell == nil )
        cell = [[[DreamTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];

    Dream *dream = [dreamsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell dreamLabel].text = [dream dreamContent];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    cell.dayLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dream date]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    cell.timeLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dream date]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` is being raised (check your console).

You need to ensure that when `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is called on your `UITableViewDelegate`, the count is correct for the section of the cell that was deleted via `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. i.e. If there were 10 elements in section 0 and you delete one of them via `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` **must** return 9 for section 0.

Comment: I've tested for that, but it doesn't seem to be the problem - please see the updated post.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the crash that's occurring (stack-trace, console output etc.).

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've thought to include that earlier..

I've updated the original post with the stack trace. There is no error, however, output to the console.

Anyway.. looks like the culprit is `UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. I searched a bit on Google for any previous encounters with this method, but couldn't find anything..

I've updated the original post, also, with the method that is calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: Hm, well, I'm not too sure what happened there, but it seems to have fixed itself somehow. I'll post again if the problem returns.